# How to add custom slangs into spaCy's norm_exceptions.py module?

Tags: nlp, spacy

SpaCy's documentation has some information on adding new slangs [here](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#norm-exceptions).

However, I'd like to know:

**(1) When should I call the following function?**

```
lex_attr_getters[NORM] = add_lookups(Language.Defaults.lex_attr_getters[NORM], NORM_EXCEPTIONS, BASE_NORMS)
```

The typical usage of spaCy, according to the introduction guide [here](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101), is something as follows:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
# Should I call the function add_lookups(...) here?
doc = nlp(u'Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')
```

**(2) When in the processing pipeline are norm exceptions handled?**

I'm assuming a typical pipeline as such: tokenizer -> tagger -> parser -> ner.

Are norm exceptions handled right before the tokenizer? And also, how is the norm exceptions component organized with respect to the other pre-processing components such as stop words, lemmatizer (see full list of components [here](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#language-data))? What comes before what?

---

Am new to spaCy and much help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm exceptions are part of the language data and the attribute getter (the function that takes a text and returns the norm), is initialised with the language class, e.g. `English`. You can see an example of this [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/68226109f4a128e299673f508dc12488c2e62d34/spacy/lang/en/__init__.py#L22). This all happens *before* the pipeline is even constructed.

The assumption here is that the norm exceptions are usually language-specific and should thus be defined in the language data, independent of the processing pipeline. Norms are also lexical attributes, so their getters live on the underlying lexeme, the context-insensitive entry in the vocabulary (as opposed to a token, which is the word in context).

However, the nice thing about the `token.norm_` is that it's writeable – so you can easily add a [custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) that looks up the token's text in your own dictionary, and overwrites the norm if necessary:

```
def add_custom_norms(doc):
    for token in doc:
        if token.text in YOUR_NORM_DICT:
            token.norm_ = YOUR_NORM_DICT[token.text]
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(add_custom_norms, last=True)
```

Keep in mind that the `NORM` attribute is also used as a feature in the model, so depending on the norms you want to add or overwrite, you might want to only apply your custom component  *after* the tagger, parser or entity recognizer is called.

For example, by default, spaCy normalises all currency symbols to `"$"` to ensure that they all receive similar representations, even if one of them is less frequent in the training data. If your custom component now overwrites `"€"` with `"Euro"`, this will also have an impact on the model's predictions. So you might see less accurate predictions for `MONEY` entities.

If you're planning on training your own model that takes your custom norms into account, you might want to consider implementing a custom language subclass. Alternatively, if you think that the slang terms you want to add should be included in spaCy by default, you can always submit a [pull request](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pulls), for example to the English [`norm_exceptions.py`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/norm_exceptions.py).

Comment: Tks for the great answer and prompt reply! Implementing a custom language subclass seems appropriate as language use in my case is industry-specific and country-specific. I'll train my own word2vec model per the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#word-vectors). During training, will words be normalized 1st (e.g. "cos" -> "because") before training the word vectors? I'd like to follow the example you gave on currency symbols and 1st normalize some words so they have the same vectors / representation although they have different `ORTH` values.

Comment: spacy (2.0.18):
attribute 'norm_' of 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' objects is not writable